# How to convert a date string from Rails into Swift

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, date, datetime

Please bear with me as I'm new to Swift: I'm writing a little app that calls an API (Rails) which return some data. The problem I'm having is that the date provided by the API comes like this: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sssZ` my function expects `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` **Please note the extra second**

Here's my function:

```
public func dateFromString(date: String, format: String) -> NSDate {

    if dateFormatter == nil {
        dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    }

    dateFormatter!.dateFormat = format
    return dateFormatter!.dateFromString(date)!
}
```

On the console, when I try to run the app I get this:

`date   String  "2015-04-13T12:48:23.310Z"`

`format String  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`

Any ideas on how I should resolve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do if you use the `SSS` as format string, like below.

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

See also: [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: How could I use the format string in the function above?

Comment: Maybe `dateFromString(date, format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")`. How do you use that function `dateFromString` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
func dateFromate(_ stringTime:String) -> String{
    //"2015-04-13T12:48:23.310Z"
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    guard let date2 = formatter.date(from: stringTime) else{
        return stringTime
    }
    let date1 = Date()
    return date1.offset(from: date2)
}
```